# Publishing a project *without* publishing web.config?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, publish

I've been publishing projects in Visual Studio Professional 2015 (C#) for about a year now.  I have always just set up a publishing profile in the Web One Click Publish toolbar, and then clicked the Web Publish icon to publish the entire project to our Intranet.

Due to some change in the server setup (servers aren't my thing...), they now want us to publish everything *but* web.config, as they have added something to the config file that works in all of our environments.  Not sure why we can't just copy that locally, but whatever.

So, my question is; is there a way to publish everything except the web.config file?  I noticed that you can publish multiple files if you do the shift/arrow to highlight them, but as soon as you include a folder in your selection you lose the right-click ability to publish files.

Comment: You can exclude specific files by changing the project settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

Comment: What do "they" expect to do when there's a config change that needs to be included in a deployment?  It seems to me that whatever was added to the config file should be added in source control, not manually tracked only on the production server.

Comment: Shouldn't "they" just be setting whatever they need on the site root (default) and allowing other sites to inherit those settings?

Comment: @David - I just do what I'm told.  This is the first time after 6 projects that they're following a new directive.  I just gotta get it done, I'll let the policymakers determine if it was a good idea or not.

Comment: @nbokmans - Setting the Build Option parameter to "None", as described in the linked article, seems to have done the trick.  Thanks!